# Computing FX forward delivery dates for 1M rates on end of the month

Tags: fx

Up to now, I have been unable to find a clear explanation on the calculation of the forward delivery date for 1M. I understand that when the spot delivery date is e.g. 14-Jan, then the 1M delivery date equals 14-Feb, given that it is a working day and not a holiday, otherwise move forward.

But what is the result for when the spot delivery date is 31-Jan as there is no 31-Feb? Where does it map to?

Many thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in another thread by Phil H in a more general way than my question above.

See [Computing FX forward delivery dates](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/computing-fx-forward-delivery-dates)